# How to giving validation for dojo datetimepicker using struts validation xml

Tags: struts2

i trying to give validation to the dojo datetimepicker using struts 2 validation xml but no success if someone has gone through the same scenario do help me out

```
<s:label value="Joining Date"/>
 <sx:datetimepicker name="joiningDate" displayFormat="dd/mm/yyyy"/>
```

and in the validation xml i write

```
 <field name="joiningDate">
     <field-validator type="required">
          <message>Select Date.</message>
      </field-validator>
  </field>
```

problem is when i click submit the page submit even if the joinindate field is empty means validation field in not applied

Comment: do you have other fields in this form with validator, which is working?

Comment: What is value of `joiningDate` in action after sumbit?

Answer (score 0):

Just add required Attribute to the  tag.

i,e

```
<sx:datetimepicker name="joiningDate" displayFormat="dd/mm/yyyy" required="true"/>
```

it should work...!

Cheers 
Karthikeyan

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
<field-validator type="date">
    <param name="min">01/01/1990</param>
    <param name="max">01/11/2012</param>
    <message>Birthday must be within ${min} and ${max}</message>
</field-validator>
```